# XCUITest to background the app is returning the wrong XCUIApplication.State

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I have a XCUITest that requires the app to be put in the background. My understanding was that when pressing the home button the app would be put into the background, which I have coded as such:

```
XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
sleep(2)
XCTAssertEqual(app.state, .runningForeground)
```

However, as the assertion states, the app is seemingly running in the foreground. Is this an incorrect implementation on my part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS Apps do not go to the background immediately – they have time to save data in case the app will be terminated in future.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background

Furthermore `.state` returns the results asynchronously. Read more in Discussion
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2877401-state

That's the reason you should use `wait` function as you did in your own answer
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2921487-wait

Answer (score 3):

Replacing...

```
sleep(5)
XCTAssertEqual(app.state, .runningForeground)
```

with...

```
let background = app.wait(for: .runningBackground, timeout: 5)
XCTAssertTrue(background)
```

has resolved the issue.

I guess I had to explicitly wait for the expected state to happen.